# Kotlin - Is it possible to initialize companion object before the init block in a class?

Tags: oop, static, kotlin, companion-object, static-initializer

Is it possible to initialize an `companion object` before the `init` block in a Kotlin class? If so, how? If not, is there a way to accomplish the same thing.

I have the following scenario,

```
class A(val iname: String) {
  init {
    foo.add(this)
  }

  companion object B {
    @JvmField val STATIC = A("hi")
    @JvmField val foo = mutableListOf<A>()   
  }

  fun printAllStatics() {
    for (a in foo) {
      print(a.iname)
    }
  }
}
```

and calling `printAllStatics` causes a null-pointer exception.

Comment: IMO it is like you want. What's your error?

Comment: Sorry, my MWE did not showcase the actual problem. My mistake

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The property initializers and `init` blocks are executed in exactly the same order in which they are placed in a class/object body. Here's an example:

```
companion object B {
    init {
        print("1 ")
    }

    @JvmField val foo = mutableListOf<A>().apply { print("2 ") }
    @JvmField val bar = mutableListOf<A>().apply { print("3 ") }

    init {
        print("4")
    }
}
```

<sup>It will print `1 2 3 4`.</sup>

So, in your case, swapping the two declarations in the `companion object` is enough:

```
companion object B {
    @JvmField val foo = mutableListOf<A>()   
    @JvmField val STATIC = A("hi")
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Just change the order of lines:

```
@JvmField val foo = mutableListOf<A>()
@JvmField val STATIC = A("hi")
```

Before you used `foo` in `A` but it wasn't initialized.